# Disk space storage in a table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

Can we store drive space details of a server in a table and also it needs to be trigger an alert email on weekly basis ??

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek into `sys.dm_os_volume_stats()`

**Example**

```
 Select Distinct  
       ServerName   = @@SERVERNAME
      ,LogicalDrive = sds.logical_volume_name
      ,Drive        = sds.volume_mount_point
      ,TotalSpace   = sds.total_bytes/1048576
      ,SpaceAvail   = sds.available_bytes/1048576
 From sys.master_files sms
 Cross Apply sys.dm_os_volume_stats(sms.database_id, sms.FILE_ID) sds
 Order By SpaceAvail asc
```

**Returns**

```
ServerName                      LogicalDrive    Drive   TotalSpace  SpaceAvail
JOHNCAPPELLETTI\MSSQLSERVER02   TI106398W0F     C:\     698658      366114
```

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'sys.dm_os_volume_stats'.